# How to modify Hibernate entity effectively(Using Java8 lambda's or anything else)

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, entities, lambda

I am having simple scenario when I am getting Entity from DB and modify it.

I dont know which fields are being modified so I am just getting the current entity from db and set all values by the new DTO(newModifiedUserDTO).

The code is getting cluttered, ugly and long.

Maybe you could advice me(Using java 8's lambda's or any other Technic how to make this code shorter and effective ?

```
 @Transactional
@Override
    public void modifyUserEntity(UserEntityDTO newModifiedUserDTO) {
        UserEntity oldUserEntity = usersRepository.findByUsername(newModifiedUserDTO.getUsername());

        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setFirstName(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getFirstName());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setLastName(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getLastName());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setEnteredCompany(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getEnteredCompany());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setCountry(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getCountry());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setState(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getState());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setCity(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getCity());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setAddress1(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getAddress1());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setAddress2(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getAddress2());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setZipCode(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getZipCode());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setTelephone(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getTelephone());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setFax(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getFax());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingCountry(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingCountry());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingState(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingState());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingCity(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingCity());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingZip(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingZip());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingTelephone(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingTelephone());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingFax(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingFax());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingAddress1(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingAddress1());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setShippingAddress2(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getShippingAddress2());
        oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity().setWorkspace(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity().getWorkspace());
        oldUserEntity.setModifyDate(CisUtils.getCurrentDate());

    }
```

According to some suggestions I tried to use Spring utils for this:

```
 copyProperties(newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity(), modifiedUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity(), "firstName", "lastName", "enteredCompany",
            "country", "state", "address1", "address2", "zipCode","telephone","fax","shippingCountry","shippingCity","shippingZip","shippingTelephone","shippingFax","shippingAddress1",
            "shippingAddress2","workspace");
```

But for some reason the changes weren't reflected in the database(using hibernate)

any ideas?

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: It would be much less cluttered if you used a variable for `oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity()`and for `newModifiedUserDTO.getExternalUsersEntity()`.

Comment: Ill still need to map everything. shorter lines - you right. but same amount of lines

Comment: IMO, you're trying to reduce simple, trivial code. Sure you could use reflection magic like Dozer or BeanUtils, but you would lose readability and the ability to refactor the code safely. Renaming a property of one of the objects would cause a silent bug at runtime rather than a compilation error.

Comment: I am just trying to shorten this code. thought maybe some Lambda's would help. To keep it that way it's really ugly

Answer (score 0):

Check Apache BeanUtils. It has `copyProperties()` method which copies over all values from one object to another. There is a similar method (same class, same name) in Spring framework too; the latter allows specifying properties *not* to copy which might be useful.

Comment: Then use Spring's utility which allows specifying those you don't want to copy.

Comment: "for some reason the changes weren't reflected in the database". I use the same tool and can successfully persist using Hibernate. You need to be more specific and do some more investigation for us to help you. In fact, you should have opened another question because the added bit is completely irrelevant to the initial question.

Comment: Hi Mindas, Excuse me if I had to put the edit within another question. I am modified an internal entity (oldUserEntity.getExternalUsersEntity()) and after invoking copyProperties the values not being overriden